# During dev, how can I block page load until watchify finishes?

Tags: javascript, browserify, watchify

Here's a typical workflow:

1. Edit JS file
2. Save file, watchify automatically starts rebuilding it for me
3. alt-tab to browser
4. ctrl+R to reload page

That's great, except if watchify takes longer than steps 3 and 4, it sucks because you either get the stale code or an error.

Is there an easy way to guarantee that doesn't ever happen? Like a way for watchify to signal to my server that it should wait another split second before trying to load the requested page? If such a thing doesn't exist, how do people deal with this problem in practice?

I must suck at Googling because I can't even find people talking about this problem except [this](https://github.com/domenic/client-side-packages-demo/tree/with-grunt-etc) which says "Add a simple (Node-based) server that will block on requests until the watch is done running: this would avoid the always-frustrating phenomenom of reloading the page only to find the watch hasn't quite run yet." -- but unfortunately that's an entry in a todo list, not something that exists in that repo.

Comment: can you use nodemon and just spawn a new chrome window in your script?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Grunt or Gulp you can use the [live reload plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-livereload).

Or you can play a [beep](https://github.com/shama/grunt-beep) when the task is complete, so that you know when to reload the page.

Also it may be worth looking at [livereloadify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereloadify).

Comment: I'm not using Grunt or Gulp. livereload seems like an interesting concept, but not quite what I want - for instance, sometimes I want to keep the old version of the app running for comparison while I open a new tab to load a version with the changes I just made. That seems like it'd be impossible with livereload.

Comment: You can create a browserify plugin that emit a beep when the build is completed, otherwise I think the only solution is what you said: "a simple (Node-based) server that will block on requests until the watch is done running"

Comment: Beep is a non-starter :) yeah I probably could write my own, maybe using a file to mark when watchify is running or not... but I figured there must be somebody who has already done it to save me the trouble!